# Indefinite integral - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: integration

We have the integral $\displaystyle \int \sqrt{4-x^2} dx$, and I want to evaluate it using integration by parts. So our first step gives us:

$$ \int \sqrt{4-x^2} dx = x \sqrt{4-x^2} + \int \dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{4-x^2}} dx   $$

Now we have to deal with $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{4-x^2}} dx $. I do integration by parts again:

$$\displaystyle \int \dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{4-x^2}} dx = x^2 \displaystyle \int \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{4-x^2}} dx -2 \displaystyle \int \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{4-x^2}} dx $$

We have $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{4-x^2}} dx = \arcsin(\dfrac{x}{2})$ and $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{4-x^2}} dx = -\sqrt{4-x^2}$, we have $$\displaystyle \int \sqrt{4-x^2} dx = x \sqrt{4-x^2} +x^2 \arcsin(\dfrac{x}{2}) + 2\sqrt{4-x^2} +C $$

However, this is incorrect. Can anyone tell me where I made a mistake?

Comment: Just wondering, how did that $x^2$ end up in front of that integral? (second line)

Comment: @imranfat The $uv$ part of the integration by parts sequence ($ \int u dv = uv - \int v du$)

Comment: But $uv$ has no integral sign in front of it

Comment: @imranfat $dv = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}$ so $v = \displaystyle \int \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}$, right?

Comment: Question: do you _have_ to use integration by parts? Usually this kind of integral is done using an "intuitive" argument or using a trig substitution.

Comment: @probablyme A trig sub is the most common approach, however integration by parts should work too

Comment: @probablyme No, hadn't thought about trig and/or an intuitive argument to be honest

Comment: This type of integral is usually solved using trigonometric substitution. I'm not sure it's possible to use integration by parts. Certainly there is no use putting $dv=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}$.

Comment: You can use Parts. First step was OK. Then note that $x^2=-(4-x^2)+4$, so our second integral is $-\int \sqrt{4-x^2}\,dx+\int \frac{4\,dx}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually for this form of integrand ($\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$) we use a trig sub with $x=a\sin\theta$. In our case $a=2$.

$$x=2\sin\theta, dx=2\cos\theta d\theta$$

Substituting we have

$$\int\sqrt{4-x^2}dx=\int2\cos\theta\sqrt{4-4\sin^2\theta}\,d\theta$$

$$=4\int\cos^2\theta\, d\theta$$

We can rewrite $\cos^2\theta$ as $\cos(2\theta)/2+1/2$.

$$=2\int\cos2\theta\,d\theta+2\theta$$

Let $u=2\theta$, $du=d\theta$, then

$$=\int\cos u \,du+u$$

$$=u+\sin u+C$$

$$=2\theta+\sin2\theta+C$$

Now we use the double angle formula.

$$=2\theta+2\sin\theta\cos\theta+C$$
$$=2\theta+2\sin\theta\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}+C$$

Solving for theta in our previous substitution we have $\theta=\arcsin x/2$. Therefore

$$\int \sqrt {4-x^2}=2\arcsin \left(\frac x 2\right) +\frac x 2 \sqrt{4-x^2}+C$$